# Ошибка драйвера USB VMWare

Tags: xcode, macos, usb, vmware

[image: Ошибка внизу]

Всем добрый день!
Надеюсь тут помогут с проблемой (см. приложение).
Такое сообщение появляется когда я пытаюсь переключить устройство (*iphone*) на виртуалку (*macOS sierra*). т.е. `vm => removable dev. => iphone`

что сделал что бы решить:

1. Удалил параметр `UpperFilters` по адресу `HKLM\system\currentcontrolset\control\class\{36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}`
2. `VM` обновил до `12.5.6 build-5528349`
3. проверил фильтр `ATI` через мастер установки - его там нет

Буду рад любой подсказке! 
Спасибо!

Comment: В настройках виртуалки USB 2 или USB 3?

Comment: usb 2, при usb 3 macos не загружается - выдает ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось хитро.
По какой то неведомой причине, `VM` отказывался запускать `macos` с настройками `usb 3.0`, поэтому была установлена настройка на `usb 2.0`. Так как в машине 2 порта: 3.0 и 2.0 - провод просто был переподключен к другому порту.